# Regex in a Windows Batch File

Tags: regex, batch-file, directory

I have made a code who copy the files from a folder to another folder and rename it. But if the folder in FolderA doesn't have a F-Number then it shouldn't copy to FolderB.

```
@echo off
set "source=C:\FolderA"
set "destination=C:\FolderB"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /AD "%source%"') do (
     for /f "tokens=1" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do robocopy "%%a" "%destination%\%%b" /E
)
```

The Files in FolderA:

- **F-1234** filename
- **F-2345** filename
- **F-3456** filename
- ABC filename
- **...**

The current result in FolderB:

- **F-1234**
- **F-2345**
- **F-3456**
- **ABC**

The result in FolderB should be:

- **F-1234**
- **F-2345**
- **F-3456**
- **...**

*the ABC folder would then be ignored*

How can I do that?

Comment: And.... Your question is???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /AD "%source%\f*"') do (
```

Filters for directorynames starting `f`.